# Android In-App-Billing - Error Code 5 for some users of Live App

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Some of our Users are facing error code 5 (that indicates a developer error / wrong signing, etc.) when purchasing something.

The interesting part is that it works perfectly fine on our test devices.

We're using the android-inapp-billing-v3 framework and we've also described the error on their github here: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/issues/361

Has anybody ever experiences error code 5, only for some users?